# Disable Gmail's image download popup

Tags: html, css, email, templates, gmail

I'm using Mailchimp to send out various on-boarding emails and have found it necessary to use large blocks of images to realize the designs I was handed. However when viewed in gmail the images present themselves as elements to be clicked, with the cursor changing to a pointer, even when its CSS has been explicitly set to default, in addition to presenting a number of other options such as downloading them to your computer. If you click on an image it opens up in some overlay utility built into other Google services.

I have found one work around: if you wrap the image in an anchor tag and point it at "#" the majority of the Google services are turned off. However it still ends up reloading the page and represents the cursor as a pointer.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I might disable the Google functionality wholesale to fully realize an image as a non-interactive background asset when viewed in gmail?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about using a Google service. This question would be better suited on Web Applications SE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gmail shows download icon on images of HTML Email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970661/gmail-shows-download-icon-on-images-of-html-email)

Answer (score 1):

Gmail appears to detect images within certain size constraints as downloadable attachments. To circumvent this, what worked for me was using the input type='image' to display the image within a  tag

HTML:

```
 <td><input type="image" src="MOBILE_02.jpg" width="700" height="226" alt="" style="display:block; outline:none" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just gave a response to this [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565323/disable-gmails-image-download-popup).

But I will answer it here too just in case:

Gmail appears to detect images within certain size constraints as downloadable attachments. To circumvent this, what worked for me was using the "background" attribute to display the image within a `<td>` tag. This effectively makes Gmail perceive the image as a background image, rather than as a potentially downloadable `<img>`. So for example, within your code **instead of the following**:

```
<td>
<img src="your_image.jpg" alt="Your Image" height="114" width="275"  style="border: 0 none;" />
</td>
```

**Use:**

```
<td background="your_image.jpg" valign="top" height="114" width="256" style="background-position: 0 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;" >
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:256px;height:114px;">
<v:fill type="tile" src="your_image.jpg" color="#e6e6e6" />
<v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]-->
<div>
</div>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
</v:textbox>
</v:rect>
<![endif]-->
</td>
```

Note that the VML in between the `<td>`s might be needed for older email clients to render the image properly.